# Xcode was not found, Please specify it

Tags: sencha-touch-2, xcode5, sencha-architect

I am new to **Sencha** and I am running **KitchenSink** in **Sencha**. But I am getting an error "Xcode was not found, Please specify it".

I have updated Sencha and installed everything but not able to get through this error. And I am not able to find to mention xcode path or else.

Comment: please care to mention negative vote..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was having 3 Xcode of different version. Therefore I set the path for my usable Xcode in terminal. Thats all.